# Is it possible to re-use a set of views in Android?

Tags: android

i know that it's possible to declare a "dummy" element in an XML, for example a textView, and load it with the layoutInflater and mayb change the text of it.
So what i thought is, that it might be possible to build a set of dummy views in a xml file load it with the layoutInflater change texts, imageResources and then append it to a tableLayout for example.
Let's say i have a TableRow and with an image and a text in it. Can i load this xml, change the text of the textView, change the imageResource of the image and then append this to a tableLayout?

Comment: So can you tell me what i have to search for or maybe even give me an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. After inflating you can cast the view to it's type and or access children using parentView.findViewById(id). you can also dynamically add or remove from ViwGroup's like TableLayout. When you are using ListViews you can read about the convertView. It's an example of reusing views.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got my brain working and i got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to move a view from one layout to another , you must remove the view from the layout that contains it and only then to add it to the other layout .
also , i think that a view cannot move between activities since they have a reference to the activity (as a context).

btw , you don't need the xml for creating the views , you can use simple java code (CTORs) for it . whe you create a view , you don't even have to put the view on a layout since you can use an inflater for this job (or , as mentioned , the CTOR) .